# Boost R-tree : unable to remove values?

Tags: c++, r-tree, boost-geometry

First, my code:

```
// Reads the index
bi::managed_mapped_file file(bi::open_or_create, indexFile.c_str(), bf::file_size(indexFile.c_str()));
allocator_t alloc(file.get_segment_manager());
rtree_t * rtree_ptr = file.find_or_construct<rtree_t>("rtree")(params_t(), indexable_t(), equal_to_t(), alloc);
std::cout << "The index contains " << rtree_ptr->size() <<  " entries." << std::endl;

std::ifstream inf(transFile.c_str());
std::string line;

while(getline(inf,line))
{
    transition t = transition(line);
    point A;
    A.set<0>(t.getQ1mz()-1);            
    A.set<1>(t.getQ3mz()-1);            
    A.set<2>(0.3);          
    A.set<3>(0.2);

    value_t v = std::make_pair(A,t);        
    rtree_ptr->insert(v);       

    rtree_ptr->remove(v);
}

std::cout << "Finished. The index now contains " << rtree_ptr->size() <<  " entries." << std::endl;
```

It reads the R-tree from a memory-mapped file. Then, it reads an input file, `transFile`, make ten so-called "transition" objects from it's content, and inserts them in the tree. Immediately after, it removes them. This is a useless case, but it illustrates well the problem that the removal steps don't work. The output I get is :

```
The index contains 339569462 entries.
Finished. The index now contains 339569472 entries.
```

So clearly, the size of the tree increases by ten, because the ten insertions worked like a charm ; but if the removals were working, in the end the tree should have the same size as before, which is not the case.

I have followed the syntax about removing values from an R-tree described [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/spatial_indexes/creation_and_modification.html), and all compiles properly, but for some strange reason it just doesn't remove the value. My guess might be that since it deletes by value, it might just not find the value to delete, but how can it be since the value is the one just inserted one line ago?

Comment: Maybe `equal_to_t` doesn't work?

Comment: What is the type of `rtree` ie what balancing algorithm did you use ? What is the equality function ?

Comment: What's the type of the object stored in the rtree, some 4d point? Is it really 4-dimensional? Which Boost version are you using? Does the same happen if the standard allocator is used?